# CMake does not link library

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw

My structure is actually very simple but make produces the following linker error:

> /ld.exe:
> CMakeFiles\hello.dir/objects.a(hello.cpp.obj):hello.cpp:(.text+0x2b):
> undefined reference to `Mathe::sum(int, int)'

My folder structure is:

```
  + CMakeLists.txt
    + src
    -- hello.cpp
    + lib
    -+ mathe
    --- mathe.h
    --- mathe.cpp
    --- CMakeLists.txt
```

CMakeLists.txt in lib/mathe folder looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

project(mathe LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE)

add_library(mathe SHARED)
target_sources(mathe PRIVATE mathe.cpp)
```

the one in the root dir:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(hello LANGUAGES CXX)

add_subdirectory(lib/mathe)

set(SOURCE src/hello.cpp)

add_executable(hello ${SOURCE})
target_link_directories(hello PRIVATE mathe)
target_include_directories(hello PRIVATE lib/mathe)
```

the **hello.cpp** has the following content:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mathe.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mathe m;
    int r = m.sum(2,3);
    return 0;
}
```

the lib looks like this:

mathe.h:

```
#ifndef MATHE_H
#define MATHE_H

class Mathe
{
    public:
        int sum(int, int);
    
};

#endif
```

mathe.cpp:

```
#include "mathe.h"

int Mathe::sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Comment: In `lib/mathe/CMakeLists.txt` you specify CMake version 3.2, but the variable [CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS.html) and corresponding property [WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS.html) has been introduced only in CMake 3.4. That is, setting this variable in your library doesn't enables automatic exporting of its symbols on Windows.

Comment: but that is not the problem it seems...

Comment: Oh, yes, the problem is that you have no `target_link_libraries` command, which would link your executable with the library. Instead you have `target_link_directories`, which has a little sense in your case.

Comment: ok, maybe I don't get it. what should I do?

Comment: Just replace `target_link_directories` with `target_link_libraries`. All parameters remains.

Comment: thank you, that worked. if you post it as an answer il'll give you credit by selecting it as the right solution.

Comment: The correct linkage is described in any tutorial for CMake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replacing `target_link_directories` with `target_link_libraries` solved it.